# How do i extract elements from an array and create a new one in php?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

This is the result of my current array:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "ACID TARTRIC 1KG "
    ["price"]=>
    float(44)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(6) "27.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "FIR ERT 250 "
    ["price"]=>
    float(8)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "7.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["name"]=>
    string(40) "ZDROBITOR DESCIORCHINATOR ENO 15 SMALTO "
    ["price"]=>
    float(1830)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "2.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["name"]=>
    string(40) "ZDROBITOR DESCIORCHINATOR ENO 15 SMALTO "
    ["price"]=>
    float(1830)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "5.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["name"]=>
    string(42) "ZDROBITOR DESCIORCHINATOR ENO 15 SEMIINOX "
    ["price"]=>
    float(2440)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "1.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "17"
    ["name"]=>
    string(31) "DESCIORCHINATOR ARNO 35 SMALTO "
    ["price"]=>
    float(4150)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "2.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "FERMACTIVE SC 500GR "
    ["price"]=>
    float(49)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(6) "23.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "FERMACTIVE SC 500GR "
    ["price"]=>
    float(49)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(5) "4.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "SULFOMAT 80PU 1KG "
    ["price"]=>
    float(7)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(6) "72.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(5) {
    ["sku"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "FERMACTIVE SB 500g "
    ["price"]=>
    float(59)
    ["cantitate"]=>
    string(6) "50.000"
    ["id_gest"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

As you can see there are duplicates elements, like DESCIORCHINATOR ARNO 35 SMALTO, but there cantitate(which means: quantity) it is not, also the id_gest. So, I want to create an array with no duplicates, but I also want to sum the quantity of the duplicates and also to the id_gest.
This is my try:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
                for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($result)+1; $j++) { 
                    if ($result[$i]['sku'] == $result[$j]['sku']){
                        $qty = $result[$i]['cantitate'] + $result[$j]['cantitate'];
                        //echo $qty."<br>";
                        $id_gest = $result[$i]['id_gest']."%%". $result[$j]['id_gest'];
                        $list[$i] = $result[$i]['sku']."%%".$result[$i]['name']."%%".$result[$i]['price']."%%".$qty."%%".$id_gest;
                        //unset($result[$i]);
                    }else{
                        $qty = $result[$i]['cantitate'];
                        $id_gest = $result[$i]['id_gest']."%%";
                        $list[$i+1] = $result[$i]['sku']."%%".$result[$i]['name']."%%".$result[$i]['price']."%%".$qty."%%".$id_gest;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The $list is the new array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Am I making myself clear ?

Comment: is this a hard question or   do I  not explain well what i really want ?

Comment: you want to merge the quantity and id_gest of those duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple foreach should suffice. Use the item's sku and push it inside the array as key. Example:

```
$list = array();
foreach($result as $item) {
    $sku = $item['sku'];

    if(!isset($list[$sku])) {
        // if it does not yet exist, push the whole array
        $list[$sku] = $item;
    } else {
        // if it exists already, just add the quantity
        $list[$sku]['cantitate'] += $item['cantitate'];
    }
}

// simple reindex
$list = array_values($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the structure really important ? Otherwise, you could try this :

```
$list = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
   $sku = $result[$i]['sku']; 
   $qty = @$list[$sku]['qty'] + $result[$i]['cantitate'];
   $id_gest = @$list[$sku]['id_gest'] . '%%' . $result[$i]['id_gest'];

   $list[$sku]['qty'] = $qty;
   $list[$sku]['id_gest'] = $id_gest;
   $list[$sku]['whatever'] =  $sku."%%".$result[$i]['name']."%%".$result[$i]['price']."%%".$qty."%%".$id_gest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand the loop you are doing thats why I wrote another one, which should work. If the 'sku' key is some kind of ID than

```
$noDuplicateArray = array();
foreach ($result as $item) {
    if (isset($noDuplicateArray[$item['sku']])) {
        $noDuplicateArray[$item['sku']]['cantitate'] += $item['cantitate'];
    } else {
        $noDuplicateArray[$item['sku']] = $item;
    }
}
```